Yucca stems drooping after repotting - what should I do next?
Last August, some 10 months ago, I repotted my yucca from a tall narrow oval-shaped pot into the larger pot it's in now. Ever since the repot it's been ailing, starting with dying leaves at the bottom of the stems. It took some force to remove the root ball from the previous pot, due to the opening being of a lesser diameter than the body of the pot, and one possibility is that I damaged the roots in the repotting process. I also had to add some extra compost, as the new pot is bigger, and all I had to hand was some homemade compost of dubious quality.
The bark on the main trunk feels fine and solid, but the leaves on the stems have continued to die from the lowest upwards. And the drooping stems haven't improved over time. I've been watering it in the saucer on the same weekly schedule it's had for all of its life. The water is taken up very quickly and the compost is generally very dry. A month or so after I repotted it, I relocated it to a sunnier location (loft extension with velux windows) compared with the location before repotting, but I'm doubtful that's had too much of an effect (UK weather).
I'm wondering what to do next. I found two relevant questions on this site, (1) and (2), and am wondering whether I should do something along the lines of the answer suggested in 2:- removing the yucca from the pot, thoroughly cleaning the root ball and trimming any rotten bits, clean pot, and repot again in new, commercial compost. I guess the drooping stems are probably not saveable though - not sure if I should trim these down at all?
Any advice appreciated.


UPDATE
It's been 2½ months since my original question. After cutting back all three stems about one inch above the main stem and the other advice suggested by user kevinskio, the Yucca didn't do anything at all. I waited 6 weeks or so but no signs of life. Thankfully though, the comment by user Yosef Baskin nudged me to take cuttings, and lo & behold they came to life. I smeared the bottoms with Hydro Coco rooting powder and planted them in a multipurpose compost and perlite mix. It took at least two weeks for them to sprout.


Thanks for the update!

You mention my previous answer here and the same probable causes apply.  If you repot you will set the plant back and, possibly, do more damage to the root ball.
If the stems are still firm I recommend more light and less water.  With a bigger pot there is more soil and the root ball will remain wetter longer until the plant grows roots into the new soil.
If this were my plant I would:

cut back all three stems about one inch above the main stem
reduce watering until new growth is seen then slowly increase
increase light
do not fertilize
do not repot


Would you try to root the cuttings?

@YosefBaskin it depends on how they look, if this is overwatering then no.

@kevinskio - Thank you for your answer. I will try what you suggest.
